# Find the value of of $^{2n}C_n-^{n}C_1.^{2n-2}C_n+^{n}C_2.^{2n-4}C_n-...$

Tags: combinatorics

The value of $^{2n}C_n-^{n}C_1.^{2n-2}C_n+^{n}C_2.^{2n-4}C_n-...$ is____

Comment: The first coefficient involves row property whereas the second coefficient involves column property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a set of $2n$ objects indexed by a pair of numbers, $(a, b)$, where $a\in \{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ and $b\in\{0,1\}$.

Let $S$ be all possible $n$-combinations of the $2n$ objects, without restrictions. Then $$|S| = \binom {2n}n$$

Let $A_i$ be the subset of combinations of $S$ which has neither objects $(i,0)$ nor $(i,1)$. The number of such combinations is 
$$|A_i| = \binom {2n-2}{n}$$

Similarly, $A_i\cap A_j$ would be the subset of combinations which has none of objects $(i,0), (i,1), (j,0),(j,1)$. For $i\ne j$, the number of such combinations is

$$|A_i\cap A_j| = \binom {2n-4}{n}$$

Consider the intersection $\bigcap_{i=1}^n \overline{A_i}$. By inclusion-exclusion principle,

$$\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\overline{A_i}\right|
&= \left| S\right| - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left|A_i\right| + \sum_{1\le i<j\le n} \left|A_i\cap A_j\right| - \cdots + (-1)^{n}\left|A_1\cap A_2\cap \cdots \cap A_{n}\right|\\
&= \binom{2n}n - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{2n-2}{n} + \sum_{1\le i<j\le n} \binom{2n-4}n - \cdots + (-1)^{n}\binom{2n-2n}{n}\\
&= \binom{2n}n - \binom{n}1 \binom{2n-2}{n} + \binom n2 \binom{2n-4}n - \cdots + (-1)^{n}\binom nn\binom{2n-2n}{n}\\
\end{align*}$$

Alternatively, $\bigcap_{i=1}^n \overline{A_i}$ is the subset of combinations which has some objects from $\{(1,0), (1,1)\}$, some objects from $\{(2,0), (2,1)\}$, ... , and some objects from $\{(n,0), (n,1)\}$, forming a combination of $n$ objects. Which means there is exactly one object of $(1,b_1)$, exactly one object of $(2,b_2)$, ..., and exactly one object of $(n, b_n)$. Binary strings of length $n$ correspond 1-to-1 to this subset, so
$$\left|\bigcap_{i=1}^n \overline{A_i}\right| = 2^n$$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}  (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{2n-2k}{n} &=& [z^n]: \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} (1+z)^{2n-2k} \\
&=& [z^n]: (-1)^n \left(1- (1+z)^2 \right)^n = [z^n]:  \left( 2z+z^2 \right)^n =2^n.\\
\end{eqnarray*}